# In Prometheus, is Vickers an android?

Tags: robots, alien-franchise, androids, prometheus

I was watching *Prometheus* again (I don't know why either) and Charlize Theron's performance sure has me thinking she is a robot. Could be she's just playing it as a cold, detached human, but her mannerism, tone of voice, etc. could certainly be interpreted either way.

When Janek straight up asks her if she is a robot, she doesn't deny it, just suggests that they have sex. Can androids not have sex in the Alien universe?

At one point, while speaking with Peter Weyland, she calls him father and does it in a voice very reminiscent of how Roy Batty says it to Tyrell in *Blade Runner*.

I suppose you could say she took the name Vickers to avoid the look that she was riding her father's coattails, but it is somewhat odd that her last name isn't Weyland if she was his daughter (she doesn't strike me as the type who would care what others thought about how she got to her level.)

Is Vickers an android?

I'm not steeped in Alien lore outside the core movies, so if it is definitively answered in a book or comic, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [this email interview with MTV.com](http://www.mtv.com/news/1687022/prometheus-secrets-damon-lindelof/), she isn't a robot, but the resemblance to David is also not a coincidence.

> **From: Damon Lindelof**
>
> *Vickers. Yes, she does look like David. Yes, this was intentional.*
>
> *What better way to piss off your daughter than to build the male equivalent of her? But enough about daddy issues (seriously, Lindelof, we get it!), allow me to answer your question. **Is she a robot?***
>
> ***She is not.***
>
> <sub><sup>'[PROMETHEUS' SECRETS SPILLED BY CO-WRITER DAMON LINDELOF](http://www.mtv.com/news/1687022/prometheus-secrets-damon-lindelof/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Hmm. Ok. In the movie, Peter Weyland is 104. Based on Theron's current age, she would have been 36 in the film (that's a loose analogy I realize). So Weyland was 68 when she was born. Not impossible, and he seems like the type of guy who would have cryogenically frozen some sperm.

No mention ever of Mrs. Weyland though.

Comment: @RickLiebling - Mick Jagger became a father at the age of 74. No need for frozen sperms...

Comment: Harrison Ruffin Tyler was born in 1928, 138 years after his grandfather President John Tyler was born in 1790, making the average generation 69 years.  James Doohan (1920-2005) had a daughter at the age of 80. In the 1930s two US Civil War veterans became fathers in their 90s.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oldest_fathers